# Integer Sorting Algorithms

Tags: sorting, bubble-sort, selection-sort

I would like to know what kind of sorting algorithm is the one below. I understand that it is a integer sorting algorithm but other than that I haven't figured it out:

```
void mySorter(int arr[]) {
    int a = arr.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < a-1; i++) {
        int min = i;

        for (int j = i +1 ; j < a; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[min])
                min = j;
            int temp = arr[min];
            arr[min] = arr[i]
            arr[i] = temp;
        }
    }     
}
```

Could it be a selection sort?

Comment: this is a bubble sort. One of the easiest to implement and one with the worst complexity. This one is pretty inneficient. There's swaps even if the 2 elements are ordered and there is no flag telling there was no swap done in the inner loop to end prematurely

Comment: 100% bubble sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Bubble Sort. Your code sorts the list in ascending order.

Comment: could it be a selection sort?

Comment: No, in selection sort the swap is done in the outer loop